# Queue memory leak

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, thread-safety, queue

i need some help with some issues i've been encountering.
Firts of all, my program.

I am writing a simple server-client program, where the messages sent from the server are enqued in a queue whithin an independent thread.
Then, there is another thread that reads that queue and executes the messages.

Something like this:

This would be one thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI recieveMessage(void* client)
{
    std::string msg;
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, 0, MAX_SIZE);
    while(TRUE){
        if (!((ClientInterpreter*)client)->receive(buffer,sizeof(buffer)))
            return -1;
        if (sizeof(buffer) == 0){
            memset(buffer, 0, MAX_SIZE);
            continue;
        }
        msg = string(buffer);
        ((ClientInterpreter*)client)->storeMessage(msg);
        memset(buffer, 0, MAX_SIZE);
        msg.clear();
    }   
}
```

Where storeMessage does this:

```
void ClientInterpreter::storeMessage(std::string msg)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(INmutex,INFINITE);
    incomingQueue->push(msg);
    ReleaseMutex(INmutex);

}
```

The other thread, the one that reads the queue calls in a while loop this function:

```
std::string ClientInterpreter::getIncomingMessage() {

    std::string retorno;
    WaitForSingleObject(INmutex,INFINITE);  
    if( incomingQueue->empty() ){
        ReleaseMutex(INmutex);
        return "0";
    }   
    retorno = incomingQueue->front();
    incomingQueue->pop();
    ReleaseMutex(INmutex);
    return retorno;

}
```

First of all, i dont know if i am using the mutexes wright, but it works(no concurrent access error shows up), so i dont bother.

i ran a profiler over this and i am getting an enormous amount of memory leaks, all of them from queue::push_back.
Like the pop function isnt destroying the objects. Does it have to do anything with the Threads?
Is there anything else i am doing wrong?

Comment: output the size of `incomingQueue`, you are probably inserting strings way more often than you are removing them

Answer (score 0):

Your code generally seems alright to me. When you say queue::push_back(), you mean push, right? Because you correctly use push() in your code. Hopefully you didn't use push_back() on accident, because that would be deque::push_back(), not queue.

Onto 2 minor points.

The first point is on

```
if (!((ClientInterpreter*)client)->receive(buffer,sizeof(buffer)))
        return -1;
```

Here, would it return a different result if the ! touched `(((ClientInterpreter*)client)->receive(buffer,sizeof(buffer)))` rather than `((ClientInterpreter*)client)->receive(buffer,sizeof(buffer))`? I'm asking because you may be more aware than I am. I'm usually terrible about being extra careful and covering my bases with extra parenthesis, so I'm not completely sure on the effect on the syntax.

The second point, and I know this is nitpicky, but maybe `recieveMessage(void* client)` being misspelled and `receive` being spelled correctly might be doing something elsewhere where we can't see.

If this doesn't help, give us a little more information on your tests and their results. Are you getting an explicit seg fault? Or are you just noticing certain leaks here and there? Have you tried gdb? etc.

Comment: Dont worry about the misspells, i am using visual studio and generally it helps you with those errors(those might be because english is no my native language).
Other than that, i am not experiencing any issue. Just huge memory leaks. Really large. It could be bacause i am reading much slower than writing, but i am not sure about that

Comment: So, in your `while(TRUE)` loop, you have the `continue;`
Would it possibly be better to take that out and just put an else in for the rest of the code, and leave any universally used bits to follow the `else` block?

Comment: Sorry if that took a while, I was out doing something with family for about an hour or so.